# Convert googletag to custom template in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

### Intro

So I want to add advertisements on multiple pages. To do so, I create a tag for every page that only will be shown on that specific page. Every page has either a leaderboard or a leaderboard and other smaller ads; here's an example:

```html
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot(OurAdUnitPath, [728, 90], 'leaderboard').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

### Issue

While trying to understand the [Custom Template API](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/api), I'm now trying to convert this to a custom template. However, whatever I do, it seems to fail displaying the ads.

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong in my code down below?

### Full custom template code

| Props | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data.ad_types | Which ad types we want to add to the page | [{ ad_type: 'leaderboard' }] |
| data.ad_id | The ID of the target | leaderboard |

```js
const copyFromWindow = require('copyFromWindow');
const injectScript = require('injectScript');
const setInWindow = require('setInWindow');
const createArgumentsQueue = require('createArgumentsQueue');

// Get ad ID and types from data
const adTypes = data.ad_types;
const adId = data.ad_id;

injectScript("https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js");

let googletag = copyFromWindow('googletag');
googletag = setInWindow('googletag', googletag || {cmd: []}, true);
googletag = copyFromWindow('googletag');

googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  // Loop through all the ad types and define the slots
  for(let i = 0; i < adTypes.length; i++) {
    const adType = adTypes[i].ad_type;
    googletag.defineSlot(OurAdUnitPath + adId + '/' + adType, [728, 90], adType).addService(googletag.pubads()); 
  }
  
  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.enableServices();
});

googletag.cmd.push(function () {
  googletag.display(adId);
});

// Call data.gtmOnSuccess when the tag is finished
data.gtmOnSuccess();
```

Comment: I doubt this can work in a custom template, since the point of that script is to inject something into the DOM, and custom templates do now allow that.